# Solve recurrence: T(n) = T(logn) + logn

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, recurrence-relations, asymptotics, computational-complexity

I am struggling to find a f(n) so that T(n) = $\Theta$(f(n)). I can only think of one upper bound, that is: $log^{*}(n) \cdot logn$

Any suggestion about what may f(n) be? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let’s think about the recursion tree(path) for this recurrence.  There will be $\log^*(n)$ levels, and each subproblem at level $i$ has one problem of size $\log^{(i)}n$ where $\log^{(i+1)}n = \log(\log^{(i)}n)$ and $\log^{(i)}n = \log n$.  As a result, for the upper bound we have
$$T(n) = \log n+T(\log n) = O(\sum_{i = 0}^{\log^*(n)}\log^{(i+1)}n) = O(\log n)$$
The last equality is true because $\log n<\frac{1}{2}n$ for large enough $n$, and $\log^{(i+1)}n<\frac{1}{2^i}\log n$ and use geometric series.  Moreover it's not hard to see $T(n) = \Omega(\log n)$.  Therefore $T(n) = \Theta(\log n)$.